# Can't get closure to close over variables

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm working with `Parse` and I'm trying to store an objects unique identifier that `Parse` gives you. Here's the code to help make sense of this.

```
    var objectID = ""
    var object = PFObject(className: "class")
    object["columnTitle"] = "String Data"
    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success, error) -> Void in
        guard error == nil else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        objectID = object.objectId!
    }

    print(objectID)
```

So I thought when I ran the app the print statement would print out the objectId that `Parse` gives you but it doesn't. If I add the print statement inside the closure it is definitely getting the value I'm expecting. It seems like the print statement is running before the value can be changed. Any idea how to fix this? I'm assuming using `GCD`?

All of this is inside `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: I believe that you will get the new object id when you query the object back from parse

Comment: thats because `saveInBackgroundWithBlock` is running in another thread which is called when process is completed and you are doing `print(objectID)` in `Main thread`

Comment: Thanks! How can I (not sure if I'm asking this properly) move the objectID info thats changed in the closure to the main thread so the variable is updated?

Answer (score 1):

`saveInBackgroundWithBlock` is an asynchronous call. If you print the object ID with in the block, it gets printed while the block is executed in a different thread.

If you place the `print` outside the block, it will be the immediate next statement executed after the call to `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`. You should place break points in these two statements and understand the behavior.

You could define a method which contains the object ID related processing code and call that method at the end of your  `saveInBackgroundWithBlock`

Comment: Do I do this though GCD? If so how do I do that?